# if array returns no results, display no results message

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function named `ShowRecords($sql)`, within the function I have this code:

```
function ShowRecords($sql) {
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $results[] = $result;
    }
    return array("results" => $results, "PageNavi" => $table_display);
}
```

I have a number of pages and on each I have this foreach loop:

```
$array = ShowRecords($sql);
foreach($array["results"] as $porting) {
    //display results
    echo $porting["sequence"];
}
```

What would be the best way (in the function) to show a message to say there are no results if nothing is returned? I have tried using `mysql_num_rows` but the foreach loop shows errors saying invalid argument

Is there a way I could still return the $results array to include each array item

For example, when I tried `$results[] = '';` if there was no row returned, I still get an error saying:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'sequence' because `$results["sequence"]` does not exist
```

Comment: Try with: `if(count($array["results"]) == 0) echo "no results";` before your foreach loop

Comment: i want to put some code in the function, otherwise i have to check every single page to add this before the foreach loop

Comment: Then try with a if statement before you return it: `if (count($array["results"]) == 0) $array["results"][] = "No results";`, so you don't have to check it every time and you have 'one' result in it which is "No results"

Comment: $array is outside the function

Comment: the first block of code is my function

Comment: Ah, then just use this: `if (count($results) == 0) $results[] = "No results";`

Comment: i get the illegal string offset error if i use that because the array item cannot be found

Comment: @Charles, just use isset in the function.  $results is only set if there are results...

Comment: but then i get an error on the foreach loop on each page

Comment: @Charles, this is why you need to handle the return differently based on if there are rows or not, exactly what I was saying, otherwise your code will always be messy.   You can even create a second function on how to handle the return for use in your template/view.   You don't seem to know enough about what you're doing, if you're learning then fine, but you don't seem willing to accept guidance, only code that meets your expectations.

Comment: i would just like to be able to do this inside the function and not above every foreach loop, otherwise itll take me forever to change each loop. is there a way i can set every array item to blank, for example in my while loop, rather than doing $results[] = $result inside the while loop, i could set $results[] = '' but for each table column

Comment: @Charles you should use @ to notify people when responding.  There are certainly ways to do what you're saying but the question comes down to the columns being defined.  I'm not sure I have enough information.   The hour it would take to use a 'Find' feature in an IDE would be worth it to you in the long run.  Use a second function when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quick representation but you should do some check on the page itself, not just in the function.  You could do it only on the page itself by doing this:

```
$array = ShowRecords($sql);
if (is_array($array['results'])) {
    foreach($array["results"] as $porting) {
        //display table and results here...
    }
}
```

This is how I would do it.  I would have the function return false or throw an exception if there are no results.

```
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if (!$rs or !mysql_num_rows($rs)) {
    return false;
}
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $results[] = $result;
}
return array("results" => $results, "PageNavi" => $table_display);
```

Then I would check to make sure `$array` is not false before doing the foreach loop.

```
if ($array = ShowRecords($sql)) {
    foreach($array["results"] as $porting) {
        //display table and results here...
    }
}
else {
    echo "No results!";
}
```

Comment: again, i dont want to have to edit every single page!

Comment: @Charles, well it's not good code otherwise.  I'm just giving you what you should do.  You can choose to do what you want but I would assume you would want to handle the return differently based on if it has results or if it doesn't which can only be done on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Just check that there are results in order to go into the `while` loop, meaning that if at least a single row there are results, otherwise no results:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0 ) {
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $results[] = $result;
    }
} else {
    return array("results" => "No results");
}
```

This way on each page when there are no results the query the `foreach` would only have a single item with the text `"No results"`.

Notice that `mysql` is depreciated and you probably should use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: `$rs` wouldn't exist in this context.  He said the first code block is a function.

Comment: @Devon Ah your right, didn't notice that. Then it would be the same thing but with the `while` loop.